# Is it possible to place view state in the session?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

(I have a feeling i'm making a mental error thinking this is possible, because it seems too easy, but here goes)

For my intranet web app with 20 users on slow machines, the view state is slowing down their browsers.

But the network is local and fast.

So I think to myself, why bother putting all that data on the user's browser?...Something like putting it in the database and then all the page needs to maintain is a unique key.

But then I remembered that's how session state pretty much works.

QUESTION: Am I missing something or is this really possible?

Comment: why not remove viewstate all together?

Comment: I see what your getting at.  OK, in this case, i have a repeater with 10 to 1000 items, each has a checkbox and a dropdown list and view state does the job of remembering their individual states, right?

Comment: up to 1000 items?  It's not viewstate you need to worry about, you should consider paging this repeater and providing some kind of filtering mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed you can. Scott Mitchell article on how to do it here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131036/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011707-1.aspx

You just need to keep an eye on your user numbers - this could potentially cause you problems if numbers get large.

Answer (score 1):

Although this does not directly answer your question, I would look at inspecting what elements on your page actualy need viewstate to be loaded, you can disable it a page level, buy adding in the page declaration or on a per control basis.

`<%@ Page EnableViewState=”false” %>`

`<asp:TextBox id=”Textbox1” runat=”server” EnableViewState=”false” />`

I would highly recommend reading this article, it contains some really good insight as to how viewstate works, and some of the problems it can cause.

http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx[enter link description here](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx)